# Quickest way to convert a spreadsheet to web form

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, ods

There is often a situation where some business logic starts from the spreadsheet (Google, ODS, XLSX). You can enter data to some cells and upon that data, some other cells are calculated. Later often it is required to convert that into a web form. Usually, then the junior dev makes it manually with JS and then the front-end guy implements the design.

I Googled but didn't find it. I just wonder why there isn't already a tool that would provide me with the undesigned HTML and JavaScript for example (could be another language) where all the cells from the spreadsheet that didn't have a formula in it would be input areas and the ones with formula in it will be just uneditable text.

Comment: It's a pretty common problem, but this is not a site for software/tool recommendations. If you are attempting to build a solution that does the conversion yourself, we might be able to help if you describe the code problem, otherwise, this is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial tool named "Table2Web" that transforms xlsx files into web forms.

Have a look here for an example with an `IF` function: https://fabbrain.de/table2web-doku/if.html

And here is an example with a `VLOOKUP` function: https://fabbrain.de/table2web-doku/vlookup.html

When you inspect the web form then you'll find CSS classes that give you a hint which xlsx sheet / xlsx cell is mapped to that HTML element, e.g. "t2w_sheet_sheet1" or "t2w_celladdress_A1".